# Can I package a Node.js App as a Java EAR

Tags: java, node.js, ear, java-server

Let's imagine that your company asked to develop a real-time chat application and wanted it to be finished in hours. Since you already know that it's super duper easy with Node.js, you developed it in Node.js but the company uses Java Application Servers(like WebSphere, JBoss or WebLogic).

So the server administrator expects .EAR files to deploy.

Is there any way to provide an .EAR file that runs your Node.js app behind?

Comment: "runs your Node.js app behind". What does this mean? Is there an actual node server also running on this box? Who services the inbound requests? The app server? My point is, think about this a bit, _how would this ever possibly work_?

Comment: My advice would be, find one of the several real-time chat examples for Java websocket libraries and tailor the implementation to your needs.

Comment: This is not a real scenario. I just wanted to learn if somehow we can do it.

Comment: Maybe we can pack node.js executable and the app then use java to start node.js with proper parameters to run server?

Comment: Ok, but at that point, you are literally just running a node.js server. Why get the java app server involved at all? Also, good luck figuring out how to route inbound requests unless you use two completely different ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is so frigging dirty that any sane checks on the released EAR should kill you on place. that being said, yes, it's possible. you have to know a bit of things first.

1. is the target JVM is enough priviliged to run processes or security on the execute right sufficently lax to enable the JVM to execute shell process by using it's API methods. (i'm talking about Java security, not OS security)
2. you must know first hand exactly which type of OS the ear container is running on.
3. the EAR/WAR must be "expanded" to a real filesystem known by the OS.
4. you must know if the credential under which the ear container have enough privilege to execute a OS command.

once you know exactly those four points, this is no biggie to use the Process java API to execute a Node.js process that the executable (statically linked and OS compatible) is conveniently to a known position...

even as Bruno Grieder said, sharing port is not possible, so you'll just have the web application acting as a front proxy for the "real" application running on Node.js, HTTP or HTTPS being not relevant at all as the final communication between the web application container and the web application itself is no longer encrypted.

awwww... so cute ... :) but, you have to know that using a sneaky method like this in company environment, is not a good thing.

Comment: As I mentioned before, this is NOT a real world scenario. I just want to know if there is a way to do it. If so, then developers can make a container for applications written in nodejs and server as java app. BTW, can you make any working example for this?

Comment: no, i don't have time for that, i took a fancy as the problem was an interesting one, the implementation of such solution is up to you. i've nothing against company guidelines anyway, they are usually sanely defined to avoid lack of ressources of the production staff against a possible production problem involving software solution. the real problem is on your hierarchy that didn't evaluate cost or just want a "do it now" solution.

Comment: As I said before, this is not a real scenario. Nobody asked me to do a chat app and certainly nobody should be willing to hide a nodejs app in a java ear, including me. And I am also not employed as a programmer, i am a DBA interested in node.js that's it. But if somehow in someway if would be possible to do it, it would be a bridge between java and nodejs that may change lots of things imho.

Comment: well, if you want to "bridge" things between nodejs and java, you can use multiple solutions, like proxying, webservice, messaging, etc... your question stated "how to package nodejs in an EAR" so this solution a way to "embed/package", but that doesn't mean that other possibilities are out of question.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You cannot properly package a "pre-installed" nodeJS inside an ear.

NodeJS installation differs between Windows and Linux; the EAR would not be portable.

On a side note, I would not like to be in your shoes, should the server administrators learn that you are packaging executables not meant to be run on the JVM, inside the EAR.

(note1: as noted in the comments above by @mlan, it would be impossible to share ports between the JVM and nodejs process - faking it would require a fronting reverse proxy dispatching HTTP requests, assuming all traffic is HTTP)

(note2: don't put me wrong, you can put anything in a EAR, including executables that you trigger from Java using `ProcessBuilder` for instance, but that a last resort workaround)